# How do I install build-essential without an Internet connection?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I can't install it. Qhen I am installing build-essential_11.4build1_amd64.deb getting error of wrong architecture still I am using amd turion 64 and then i am trying to install build-essential_11.4build1_i386.deb getting error of Dependency is not satisfiable:g++(>=4:4.3.1)

I don't have an internet connection in ubuntu that's why I have downloaded from windows so what to do now?

Comment: How are you exactly installing `build-essential`? It seems that you've downloaded a `.deb` file. Don't do that. You're not on Windows - in Ubuntu we use repositories. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` in a terminal and report the results or exact error output in your question by editing it.

Comment: sir i don't have internetconnection in ubuntu thats why i hv downloaded from windows so what to do now? sir  when I am using command line then they are giving error of unable to locate package build-essential

Comment: I suggest to fix your internet connection first. That will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @gertvdijk I bet that's exactly what he's trying to achieve. If your NIC isn't supported by the kernel you've to build modules from e.g. Compat-wireless

Comment: I should note that `build-essential` is a **metapackage**.  That is to say, it refers to other packages, as `build-essential` incorporates a lot of basic libraries for building and a lot of executables, so they don't bundle it up in one package, it refers to many other packages.

Answer (score 14):

Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get -qq --print-uris install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) | cut -d\' -f 2 > urls.txt
```

copy the `urls.txt` to a thumbdrive and move over to a computer with Internet Access. Download all files from `urls.txt` (if the other computer is running Linux you can use `wget < urls.txt`) and save them in a folder called `deb` on your thumbdrive.

Go back to your Ubuntu machine, plug in the thumbdrive and open a Terminal

```
sudo cp /media/YOUR_USERNAME/THUMBDRIVE_NAME/deb/* /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can install

Comment: `Unable to locate package build-essential` - if you have no network, it won't have run `apt update`, so it does not know of packages. Your only option is to install Ubuntu somewhere with internet (inside a VM) and then follow the above steps and plus you will need to move the `/var/lib/apt/lists` to the offline machine

Comment: I had to use `wget -i urls.txt` (see also [how-to-wget-a-list-of-urls-in-a-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986340/how-to-wget-a-list-of-urls-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Good answer. The last command is not working for me. It is still searching for the url online