# How do I install Jensen Scandinavia Airlink 100ac driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.
I am trying to follow the simple step by step guide in the accompanied pdf file to install the Linux driver for the airlink 100ac. The only internet access I have is on another laptop, and I have an 8gig usb stick which I can use. To transfer files, as I can do with the driver folder.
The step by step guide:

Installation of driver in Linux

1. Download the latest Linux driver from 
   http://www.jensenscandinavia.com/downloads
2. Copy the driver to your local folder.
3. Open console
4. Unzip the driver
5. Enter `make`
   (and click enter)
6. Enter `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
   (and click enter)
7. If you have the 
   Air:Link 500ac - enter 
   (and click Enter)
   `sudo modprobe 8812au`. If you have the 
   Air:Link 100ac - enter 
   `sudo modprobe 8821au` 
   (and click Enter)

The driver should now be installed and your 
AL100AC / 500AC is ready for use.

How do I install this? On step 5, when I type `make` and press enter, it says :

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

And on step 6, I suppose I need internet connection? I don't have an internet connection before I get the usb dongle to function. Can I get `build-essential` via usb?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download build-essential package (32/64 bit: uname -m) on the laptop with Internet Access from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential
2. Copy the build-essential package onto your USB-Stick
3. Install the package onto your laptop:

> sudo dpkg -i /path/to/build-essential*.deb

4. Now type:

> make clean

5. Create/compile driver

> make

6. Install driver

> sudo make install

7. Load driver

> sudo modprobe 8821au

Driver should be installed

Comment: When I type: "sudo dpkg -i build-essential.deb", I get a message saying that it can't install because it depends on g++ (>= 4:4.4.3), and that package g++ is not installed.

Comment: Yes, build-essential is a meta-package and has a lot of dependencies. Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334136/how-do-i-install-build-essential-without-an-internet-connection

Comment: You will also need linux-headers.