# Install Realtek RTL8111/RTl8168 driver without internet connection

Tags: drivers, gcc, realtek

So I've been following this guide: https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/ and a couple of others (this one has helped the most). I just can't get the driver installed. When I try to run the autorun.sh file from I first got an error saying that make wasn't a command. I fixed this by following this right here: [How do I install build-essential without an Internet connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334136/how-do-i-install-build-essential-without-an-internet-connection?newreg=c1147add3f3940deb3c4d6ffd62ca78e)
This helped, but then when I went to run the install file again, I got an error saying gcc wasn't a command. So then I used that same tutorial but replaced the build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) with gcc. When I try to install that I get this an error because I'm pretty sure it's trying to download more things within the install of gcc. So I went and downloaded and installed everything on the list The following additional packages will be installed: but it still didn't work. I'm lost, if anyone could offer help please do so. Thanks! I'll be answering any questions as soon as I can to try and get this resolved.

Comment: Why don't you temporarily connect using your phone?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Connect to what? How would I do that?

Comment: Connect to the Internet using your smartphone as a USB modem?

Comment: I'll try that but who knows if downloading the packages will work out as planned...

Comment: So I've followed that same tutorial that I used for build-essential and when I try to do sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils libimobiledevice-dev libimobiledevice-utils it says unable to locate package ipheth-utils and libimobiledevice-utils even though I just downloaded those packages. Any way I could fix this that you know of, @Pilot6   Thanks

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt update` first to get list of packages.